# Solr: Excluding certain HTML tags or only including certain tags within indexes

Tags: apache, solr, solr-cell

I'm currently using Solr-Cell to grab the contents of several html pages and index them. The issue is that I have a menu in the header which is shown on all the pages. This Menu and all its items are appearing within the search results. I don't want this to be indexed.

How would you accomplish this?

Is it possible to exclude certain DIV (with a classname or id) ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you do the test, you will see that the way Tika is used in Solr, it strips most of the HTML, including divs, and classes and ids attributes.

So, you may not be able to get the granularity you want and may need to use something like RegexReplaceProcessorFactory UpdateRequestProcessor to remove undesired parts by matching against pure text.

If you called Tika directly from your code, you have more control over it and can set IdentityHtmlMapper to not do HTML filtering.

Comment: Another caveat to this problem is that I'm a beginner to SOLR. I will research RegexReplaceProcessorFactory. I am not sure about separating TIKA from SOLR at this time. My code is 95% complete and the only thing left for me to do is to remove the menu items from the results. Otherwise, I would invest the time.